# Tensorflow Universal sentence encoder (lite) crashes

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, out-of-memory, text-processing

I am having problem when I run the Tensorflow's universal sentence encoder implementation. I have a lot of text files with a big texts inside. I have tried both universal sentence encoder and its lite version. When I run them on a subset of the files, they work, but if I run them on all files, they both crash. Here is a code segment from the lite version (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder_lite):

```
messages = [
    # Smartphones
    "I like my phone",
    "My phone is not good.",
    "Your cellphone looks great.",

    # Weather
    "Will it snow tomorrow?",
    "Recently a lot of hurricanes have hit the US",
    "Global warming is real",

    # Food and health
    "An apple a day, keeps the doctors away",
    "Eating strawberries is healthy",
    "Is paleo better than keto?",

    # Asking about age
    "How old are you?",
    "what is your age?",
]

    input_placeholder = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, None])
encodings = module(
    inputs=dict(
        values=input_placeholder.values,
        indices=input_placeholder.indices,
        dense_shape=input_placeholder.dense_shape))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    spm_path = sess.run(module(signature="spm_path"))

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(spm_path, mode="rb") as f:
    sp.LoadFromSerializedProto(f.read())
print("SentencePiece model loaded at {}.".format(spm_path))


def process_to_IDs_in_sparse_format(sp, sentences):
    # An utility method that processes sentences with the sentence piece processor
    # 'sp' and returns the results in tf.SparseTensor-similar format:
    # (values, indices, dense_shape)
    ids = [sp.EncodeAsIds(x) for x in sentences]
    max_len = max(len(x) for x in ids)
    dense_shape = (len(ids), max_len)
    values = [item for sublist in ids for item in sublist]
    indices = [[row, col] for row in range(len(ids)) for col in range(len(ids[row]))]
    return (values, indices, dense_shape)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    values, indices, dense_shape = process_to_IDs_in_sparse_format(sp, messages)
    # print('Values: ', values)
    # print('Indices: ', indices)
    # print('Dense_shape: ', dense_shape)

    message_embeddings = session.run(
        encodings,
        feed_dict={input_placeholder.values: values,
                   input_placeholder.indices: indices,
                   input_placeholder.dense_shape: dense_shape})

    corr = np.inner(message_embeddings, message_embeddings)
```

In my case, the messages are just strings of around 5K words each, and there are 20K of them.

For the lite version, the program is running for around 5-10 minutes and then just says "killed":

```
(pipeline) root@pavel-nlu:~/petar# python3 main-lite.py 
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/miniconda3/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (105,106) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
2021-05-22 11:47:21.838581: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-05-22 11:47:21.839022: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-05-22 11:47:21.841543: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2021-05-22 11:47:23.039857: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:196] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 0 passes)
2021-05-22 11:47:23.208778: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2593520000 Hz
SentencePiece model loaded at b'/tmp/tfhub_modules/539544f0a997d91c327c23285ea00c37588d92cc/assets/universal_encoder_8k_spm.model'.
Killed
```

For the normal version, I have made another question here: [tf universal sentence encoder running our of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638287/tf-universal-sentence-encoder-running-our-of-memory) with the error.

The machine I'm running on has the following specs:

```
CPU: 16 vCPUs
RAM: 60GB
Boot Source: Local 
System Disk: 40GB
Data Disk: 600GB (2 disks)
Network: 5Gb / s
```

Comment: Usually when I run out of memory, I decrease the training batch size, but here the model is already trained. I don't know how I could prevent the program from crashing.

Comment: I suspect the problem comes from either the np inner product or the message_embedding computation.